# Ubuntu 18.04 Boots Slow after upgrade

Tags: boot, upgrade, 18.04

I upgraded Ubuntu from 17.10 to 18.04.  Under 17.10 there is no issues with the boot -  I did a clean install and used LVM as well.   When upgrading to 18.04 I have a hang for about 35 seconds.  I have read the forums where it says to get are suggesting changes to this file `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` where I have a `uuid` device listed and change it to `Resume=None`. Before I make changes like that I do not want to end up with a system that is will not boot.  I do have a swap drive (checked) it is 8GB.   Here is the file I see on boot.  Is there something I am missing?  I have enabled boot to visual and there is a 35 second hang on this load  Running `/scripts/local-premount` ...   Am I looking at the right problem?

```
mike@mike-Inspiron-1564:~$ systemd-analyze blame

     18.479s dev-mapper-ubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2droot.device
     15.634s systemd-journal-flush.service
     11.098s lvm2-monitor.service
      8.693s systemd-udevd.service
      7.095s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      6.976s dev-loop2.device
      6.973s dev-loop0.device
      6.936s dev-loop1.device
      6.186s snapd.service
      4.835s udisks2.service
      4.658s teamviewerd.service
      4.293s apparmor.service
      3.363s networkd-dispatcher.service
      3.112s NetworkManager.service
      3.097s systemd-sysctl.service
      3.090s ModemManager.service
      2.774s accounts-daemon.service
      2.715s apport.service
      2.436s nmbd.service
      2.419s colord.service
      2.365s keyboard-setup.service
      2.189s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      1.713s smbd.service
      1.567s wpa_supplicant.service
      1.532s avahi-daemon.service
      1.518s thermald.service
      1.510s speech-dispatcher.service
      1.507s gpu-manager.service
      1.501s pppd-dns.service
      1.499s alsa-restore.service
      1.473s systemd-logind.service
      1.473s rsyslog.service
      1.448s systemd-rfkill.service
      1.290s sys-kernel-debug.mount
      1.242s systemd-remount-fs.service
      1.211s dev-hugepages.mount
      1.204s dev-mqueue.mount
      1.121s fwupd.service
      1.106s systemd-modules-load.service
      1.000s user@121.service
       692ms systemd-journald.service
       579ms grub-common.service
       562ms dns-clean.service
       530ms packagekit.service
       485ms upower.service
       406ms gdm.service
       392ms lvm2-pvscan@8:1.service
       367ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       365ms networking.service
       363ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       269ms systemd-resolved.service
       265ms plymouth-read-write.service
       264ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       236ms ufw.service
       233ms blk-availability.service
       215ms snap-core-4571.mount
       210ms systemd-random-seed.service
       206ms polkit.service
       203ms motd-news.service
       183ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       170ms snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-39.mount
       132ms snap-core-4486.mount
       105ms bolt.service
       105ms systemd-update-utmp.service
        95ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
        95ms user@1000.service
        88ms setvtrgb.service
        48ms sys-kernel-config.mount
        46ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
        35ms dev-mapper-ubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2dswap_1.swap
        19ms snapd.socket
        18ms kerneloops.service
        18ms console-setup.service
        13ms systemd-backlight@leds:dell::kbd_backlight.service
        11ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
        11ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
         9ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
         9ms ureadahead-stop.service
         8ms rtkit-daemon.service
         5ms systemd-user-sessions.service
         5ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
```

lines 59-81/81 (END)